# Changing colors on Azure Dashboard Charts and Global parameter for all tiles

Tags: azure, azure-dashboard

We have created Azure Dashboard with custom KQL queries with 5 tiles and we want to send a OPERATION ID from one page to this Dashboard page and we want all tiles to consume this PARAMETER in the query.

Is it possible to send a global query parameter and get it used by all the tiles on the Dashboard? Also is it possible to control the COLORS on the Charts rendered in these tiles on the dashboard? Can we change the colours of this pie chart rendered or that is not possible?

Any help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not supported out of the box with Azure Dashboards and don't anticipate it being either, there is a feature request but doesn't have many votes and no traction.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/11722425-tile-background-color

The best option if you wanted rich charting like this is to go towards Power BI
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/